# Can I safely disconnect this television outlet?

Tags: electrical, safety, television

I have what appears to be an old tv antenna outlet connection in our bedroom. This outlet has since been replaced (elsewhere in the room) by coaxial cable.

I would like to disconnect this cable and cover with a solid wallplate, however, want to make sure there are no hazards to leaving the wires in place in the box.

[image: Front Plate]

[image: inside box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be an issue. You could put a wire nut on the bare wires in the box or wrap each of them in electrical tape in case the same wire runs to other outlets or is connected to your coaxial distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can unscrew the terminals, keep the wires separated with individual wire nuts or other insulated wire terminating device, or just separately wrapped with electrical tape, and install a blank plate.

If you want to do it correctly, you might need to consider this part of the National Electrical Code (NEC):

> 800.25 Abandoned Cables. The accessible portion of abandoned communications cables shall be removed. Where cables are identified
>   for future use with a tag, the tag shall be of sufficient durability
>   to withstand the environment involved.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.  Just cap the wires individually with twist-on wire connectors (or other preferred device). Then cover the box with a blank cover plate.